# google python data example: pizza party

Tags: python, xml

hey i started learning python and am quite confused as how the google data library works.
google has a pizza party example over at this [link](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/wiki/WritingDataModelClasses)

can anyone here please take the time to explain how it is being done. i would be so grateful.

WHAT I UNDERSTAND:

```
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:p='http://example.com/pizza/1.0'>
  <id>http://www.example.com/pizzaparty/223</id>
  <title type='text'>Pizza at my house!</title>
  <author>
    <name>Joe</name>
    <email>joe@example.com</email>
  </author>
  <content type='text'>
    Join us for a fun filled evening of pizza and games!
  </content>
  <link rel='alternate' type='text/html'
        href='http://www.example.com/joe_user/pizza_at_my_house.html'/>
  <p:pizza toppings='pepperoni, sausage' size='large'>Pepperoni with cheese and 
sausage</p:pizza>
  <p:pizza toppings='mushrooms' size='medium'>Mushroom</p:pizza>
  <p:pizza toppings='ham, pineapple' size='extra large'>Hawaiian</p:pizza>
  <p:capacity>25</p:capacity>
  <p:location>My place.<p:address>123 Imaginary Ln, Sometown MO 63000</p:address></p:location>
</entry>
```

this is the XML feed for the pizza. why it is created i do not understand.

NOW this is the linking to the XML feed:

```
import atom.core

PIZZA_TEMPLATE = '{http://example.com/pizza/1.0}%s'

class Capacity(atom.core.XmlElement):
  _qname = PIZZA_TEMPLATE % 'capacity'
```

in PIZZA_TEMPLATE, what is "%s"?
what is atom.core?

i am a little confused. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

%s is a string placeholder, and % is the string interpolation operator. See the [Python docs on string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) for more information.

[`atom.core`](http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/atom.core.html) is a Python module to work with [Atom feeds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(standard)).

Answer (score 0):

Given that this question is about Python and involves a pizza party, I'd say you were biting off more than you can chew ...

But seriously, if you're just learning Python, start with something simpler.